# How are permissions applied to a file using set_mode?

Tags: rust

If my understanding is correct, the following code should produce an executable file. However it doesn't; it gets created, but the permissions specified aren't applied. What am I doing wrong?

```
use std::fs;
use std::os::unix::PermissionsExt;


fn main() {
    fs::File::create("somefile").unwrap()
        .metadata().unwrap()
        .permissions()
        .set_mode(0o770);
}
```

Comment: `File::metadata()` returns a `Metadata`, `Metadata::permissions()` returns a `Permission`, and that `set_mode` is just setting the mode in that copy of the permissions, it's not actually applying it to the file. (And I can't seem to find any way to do that.)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use [`OpenOptions`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/struct.OpenOptions.html):

```
use std::fs;
use std::os::unix::OpenOptionsExt;

fn main() {
    fs::OpenOptions::new()
        .create(true)
        .write(true)
        .mode(0o770)
        .open("somefile")
        .unwrap();
}
```

Comment: This should be `use std::os::unix::fs::OpenOptionsExt;`

https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/os/unix/fs/trait.OpenOptionsExt.html#examples

Comment: if you are writing to a file that already exists `OpenOptionsExt` will not _change_ permissions using `.mode(..)` shown above. But if you are creating the file for the first time then it will apply the chosen mode.

Answer (score 16):

You can also use [set_permissions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/fs/fn.set_permissions.html) for existing path

```
use std::fs;
use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;

fn main(){
     fs::set_permissions("/path", fs::Permissions::from_mode(0o655)).unwrap();
}
```