# How to compile a Unix-specific file permissions method on all platforms

Tags: rust, file-permissions

My goal is to disallow other users on a Unix system to read the content of the file.

How do I set file permissions in Linux while still allowing the program to compile for Windows?

Compiling for Unix machine, [I can do this:](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63089421/2574407)

```rust
use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;
fs::set_permissions("/path", fs::Permissions::from_mode(0o655)).unwrap();
```

But this will not compile on Windows. How can I work around that?

Comment: It's worth noting that, if possible, it's better to create the file with the right permissions. This can be done as described in the below link. But the `mode` method will only work on Unix, so you still need to conditionally compile as @munksgaard et al write below.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/28673836/2574407

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to handle this is probably with configuration attributes.

For instance, you might want something like this:

```rust
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
fn set_permissions(path: &str) {
  use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;
  fs::set_permissions(path, fs::Permissions::from_mode(0o655)).unwrap();
}

#[cfg(not(target_family = "unix"))]
fn set_permissions(path: &str) {}
```

More examples [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/attribute/cfg.html) and reference documentation [here](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html).

Answer (score 4):

Use `#[cfg(unix)]` to [conditionally compile](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) code for Unix, and `#[cfg(windows)]` or `#[cfg(not(unix))]` for a non-Unix branch.

```
#[cfg(unix)]
{
    use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;
    fs::set_permissions("/path", fs::Permissions::from_mode(0o655))?;
}

#[cfg(not(unix))]
{
    todo!();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You probably want to use Rust's [conditional compilation feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html) (Similar to `ifdef`-ing in C/C++).

You can choose to compile code on a specific operating system using:

```
// The function is only included in the build when compiling for macOS
#[cfg(target_os = "macos")]
fn set_permissions(path: &str) {
  use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;
  fs::set_permissions(path, fs::Permissions::from_mode(0o655)).unwrap();
}

#[cfg(not(target_os = "macos"))]
fn set_permissions(path: &str) {
  ...
}
```

(Keep in mind you probably need an empty stub for other platforms for the code to compile)

Supported values are:
"windows", "macos", "ios", "linux", "android", "freebsd", "dragonfly", "openbsd", "netbsd"

Or you could use more generic specifier, such as `target_family`:

```
// The function is only included in the build when compile for unix systems
#[cfg(target_family = "unix")]
fn set_permissions(path: &str) {
  use std::os::unix::fs::PermissionsExt;
  fs::set_permissions(path, fs::Permissions::from_mode(0o655)).unwrap();
}
```

Supported values: "unix", "windows", "wasm"